# How do I go a folder back and not the entire path C#?

Tags: python, c#, directory

I have my C# application and my Python script combined but I use the code on other PCs too where it is not in the same folder.

The file structure looks like this:

```
c#
 - (C# project folder) 
Python
 - The Python script
```

When I want to go find the Python script I have to put the entire path "c:/.." Is there a way to just go back a folder and go to another folder to access the Python script?

Comment: Sure you can use relative paths. As long as you make sure it's the correct path, they are relative to.

Comment: It is in 2 different folders an I have to go back one and go in another where the script is

Comment: it searches in the bin folder and not like 2-3 folders back where the Python folder is located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be helpful:

```
string fullyQualifiedExeFilename = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string parentFolder = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(folder).FullName;
string grandparentFolder = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(parentFolder).FullName;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Fully-Qualified Exe Name: '{fullyQualifiedExeFilename}'");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Folder: '{folder}'");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Parent Folder: '{parentFolder}'");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Grandparent Folder: '{grandparentFolder}'");
```

**Resources**:

- [System.Reflection Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=net-7.0)
- [Directory Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-7.0)

**Additional Resources**:

- [Path Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-7.0)
- [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0)